# What is the purpose of a package

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have been learning java and using eclipse. So my question is what is the purpose of a package, and why can't there just be projects and classes?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Answer (score 2):

Packages are a way to group/organize/separate your classes depending of the a common functionality. 
So, say you have a set of classes that deal with storing multiple objects (such as the collections package)
or you could have a package of classes that deal with File manipulation: such as the java.io.* package.

It's just a way of organizing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Manuel Manrique has said, one thing that I could think of is, packages help resolve class/interface naming conflicts

For ex: I use some-apache.jar and some-google-api.jar, assuming both have same class named `Test`, packages help resolve the conflict.

In general package naming convention is something like `org.apache.Test` or `com.google.Test`